# 1 in each row of an all zeros numpy array at particular column index given by another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

I have an array of some given size e.g 4x4 with all zeros,

```
a = np.zeros((4,4))
```

and I want to put 1 in each row at the column index given by another array

```
b = np.array([0,1,2,1])
```

so the resulted array should look like this,

```
a = 
1   0   0   0
0   1   0   0
0   0   1   0
0   1   0   0
```

How can I do this for a large array of size `(mxn)` given b of size `(mx1)`.

Thank You and Best Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple way of indexing 2D array:

```
>>> a[np.arange(len(a)), b] = 1
>>> a
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through rows in `a` and values in `b` using `zip()`:

```
for row, idx in zip(a, b):
    row[idx] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can it be achieved without for loop in a more efficient manner?